# javascript box get position x in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

[image]

[image]

I want to take the position of the box in the gray area. How can I do that?

```
                <div id="timeline">
                  <div
                    cdkDragBoundary="#timeline"
                    [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragPosition"
                    id="timelineBox"
                    cdkDrag
                    #timelineBoxRef
                  >
                    Timebox
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the position to be relative to gray area [HTMLElement.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) and [HTMLElement.offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) should do the job.
If it's some other position [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) may be handy.